# In the Church of England, can one accept communion without being confimed?

Tags: communion, anglicanism, confirmation, church-of-england

If someone is baptised as a child, but never confirmed, can such a person receive communion? I'd like the viewpoint of the Church of England.

Answer (score 7):

This comes under [Canon B15A](https://www.churchofengland.org/about-us/structure/churchlawlegis/canons/section-b.aspx#p34). The only essential prerequisite is baptism.

Other than that:

- If you're a member of the C of E, you should be confirmed (or at least want to be confirmed) to take communion.
- Any baptised person who can take communion in their own church can take communion in the C of E. (Assuming their own church believes in the Trinity.)
- If you're about to die, you can go ahead and take communion despite the other rules.
- Synod sometimes makes other provisions. In particular, children who have reached the age of reason, and expect to be confirmed when they're older, can take communion if the diocesan bishop permits it.

But see the canon law for the full details. There are also rules going the other way-- for example, Roman Catholics are forbidden by their canon law to receive communion from Anglican priests, even though Anglican canon law would permit it.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering a good answer with a solid reference to support it!